# Do I need QT Commercial License for annotation tool?

Tags: gpl, lgpl, license

I'm going to make an annotation tool for deep learning using PyQT.

Trained models are sold on the product.

My annotation tool is not sold with the product.

so, Customer can't see my annotation tool.

The annotation tool I created is only used inside the company (with few co-worker) for preparing training dataset.

In this case, is a commercial license required?

Comment: See also: [GPL FAQ - Does the GPL require that source code of modified versions be posted to the public?](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#GPLRequireSourcePostedPublic)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your objective.

PyQT is distributed under a [variety of licenses](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt/PyQtLicensing), and you can basically select the one that fits best for your purpose.

You could select the GPL license, and then run your tool as a service on a server accessible to your customers (SaaS), which does not count as distribution under the terms of GPL. This way you would not therefore need to disclose your own code to your customers.

You could again select the GPL license, distribute your product (including PyQT code) to your customers, and establish a pay-per-use model, where your customers pay you for each trained model they create. In this case you likely have to provide the source code to your customers under the GPL license (and eventually allow your customers to modify the code to by-pass your business model).

You could select the commercial license and distribute your product (including PyQT code) to your customers, and establish a pay-per-use model, where your customers pay you for each trained model they create. In this case you would not have to provide the source code to your customers.

There are many more possible ways for you to implement you business model, the common thing for all of them is that as soon as you distribute the application under GPL you have to provide the source code of your app, and to avoid that you can select the commercial license.

Comment: I'm not sure how the GPL pay-per-use model would work; you propose distributing GPL code but requiring that the customer pay for each model trained on datasets prepared with this GPL annotation tool?

Comment: well.. thanks your answer.. but I dont have plan to provide our annotation tool to anyone without my co-worker. So. as I understood, License is not needed right?

Comment: @Byung-HyunYoon Correct, if you just use it in-house and do not distribute, then the GPL license will be perfect for you. The commercial license is not needed.